# Separating directory tree traversal from code that needs to run there in python

Tags: python, filesystems, traversal

I am running simulations in a directory structure that looks like this `rootDir/*pot/*K/*Ang/lambda_*`. The asterisk having its usual wildcard meaning and being replaced with various different parameters.

In the past our group used bash for most of these tasks, in which it is very simple to use such wildcards. However, we are trying to switch to python because it is more powerful, overall. But in python things like `cat *K/file >> newfile` kinda suck, meaning much more code is generally required.

Additionally, writing the crucial code that really needs to run nested 5 loops deep kinda sucks, too, especially when you have to make changes a little further up. It's just cluttered.

So I have written a module that separates the traversal and code execution pretty decently. The advantage is that I can create a template for a given folder structure, and then just add very few lines to run different code in whatever location I want. However, it uses a hack that most of you will hate me for, and is also problematic because the code that should run is actually executed in the scope of the helper module, so one pretty much has to choose to either run all code from there, or none.

Here is the module (I've called it "actionChain.py"):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import shutil
import fnmatch
import re

j = os.path.join

class actionChain:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = os.path.abspath(path)
        self.basename = os.path.basename(self.path)
        self.firstCommands = []
        self.lastCommands = []
        self.actionSteps = []

    def setPath(self, path):
        self.path = os.path.abspath(path)
        self.basename = os.path.basename(self.path)

    def addActionSteps(self, *actionSteps):
        for step in actionSteps:
            self.actionSteps.append(step)

    def addFirstCommands(self, *firstCommands):
        for command in firstCommands:
            self.firstCommands.append(command)

    def addLastCommands(self, *lastCommands):
        for command in lastCommands:
            self.lastCommands.append(command)

    def run(self):
        currentDir = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(self.path)
        
        for c in self.firstCommands:
            exec(c)
        # Do not ever repeat this hack unless you know _very_ well what you're doing
        globals().update(locals())
       
        if self.actionSteps:
            self.actionSteps[0].run(self.actionSteps[1:])
      
        for c in self.lastCommands:
            exec(c)
        # Do not ever repeat this hack unless you know _very_ well what you're doing
        globals().update(locals())

        os.chdir(currentDir)


class actionStep:
    def __init__(self, pattern):
        self.pattern = pattern
        self.firstCommands = []
        self.lastCommands = []

    def setPattern(self, pattern):
        self.pattern = pattern

    def addFirstCommands(self, *firstCommands):
        for command in firstCommands:
            self.firstCommands.append(command)

    def addLastCommands(self, *lastCommands):
        for command in lastCommands:
            self.lastCommands.append(command)

    def run(self, subsequentSteps):

        files = os.listdir(".")
        for f in files:
            if os.path.isdir(f) and fnmatch.fnmatch(f, self.pattern):
                os.chdir(f)
                
                for c in self.firstCommands:
                    exec(c)
                # Do not ever repeat this hack unless you know _very_ well what you're doing
                globals().update(locals())

                if subsequentSteps:
                    subsequentSteps[0].run(subsequentSteps[1:])

                for c in self.lastCommands:
                    exec(c)
                # Do not ever repeat this hack unless you know _very_ well what you're doing
                globals().update(locals())

                os.chdir("..")
```

This is nice, because it allows me to use code like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import actionChain as ac

chain = ac.actionChain(".")

rootDir = ac.actionStep("mtp_to_mtp_allVT")

targetDir = ac.actionStep("target_*")

refDir = ac.actionStep("reference_*")

TDir = ac.actionStep("*K")

aLatDir = ac.actionStep("*Ang")

lambdaDir = ac.actionStep("lambda_*")

chain.addActionSteps(rootDir, targetDir, refDir, TDir, aLatDir, lambdaDir)



# Get variables from structure -v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-

targetDir.addFirstCommands(r"""
target = re.search('(?<=target_).*', os.path.basename(os.getcwd())).group(0)
print('target:', target)
""")

refDir.addFirstCommands(r"""
ref = re.search('(?<=reference_).*', os.path.basename(os.getcwd())).group(0)
print('ref:', ref)
""")

TDir.addFirstCommands(r"""
T = re.search('.*(?=K)', os.path.basename(os.getcwd())).group(0)
print('T:', T)
""")

aLatDir.addFirstCommands(r"""
aLat = re.search('.*(?=Ang)', os.path.basename(os.getcwd())).group(0)
""")

lambdaDir.addFirstCommands(r"""
l = re.search('(?<=lambda_).*', os.path.basename(os.getcwd())).group(0)
""")

# get variables from structure -^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-




# Your code goes here -v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v

chain.addFirstCommands("noAtoms = 125")

refDir.addFirstCommands(r"""
extract = open('extractedData.tsv', 'w')
extract.write('#T[K]\taLat[Ang]\tpotEne[eV]\tpotEneRef[eV]\tpotEne-potEneRef[meV/atom]\n')
""")
refDir.addLastCommands(r"""
extract.close()
""")


lambdaDir.setPattern("lambda_1.00")

lambdaDir.addFirstCommands(r"""
f = open('dUdL', 'r')
line = f.readlines()[1].split()
f.close
potEne = line[9]
potEneRef = line[10]
extract.write('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(T, aLat, potEne, potEneRef, (float(potEne)-float(potEneRef))/noAtoms))
""")

# Your code goes here -^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-



chain.run()
```

As you can see, syntax highlighting in those string codes is also an issue.

I realize that this is a rather broad question, but do you have any suggestions as to how to better tackle this problem? Less hacky? Still comparably simple to use?

These are the things I need fixed:

- "Execute code" must run within the scope of my actual script, so that it can interact with code that is not run through the "actionChain"
- I'd love to have working syntax highlighting
- No dirty hacks, but actually safe and proper code
- Still as much separation of traversal and "doing things" as possible

Comment: Have you looked into [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)?

Comment: @root No I had not! Thanks for the hint. It alleviates part of the problem. It would eliminate the need to do any traversal in cases where I don't require the string behind * in *K/ when working in *K/*Ang. However, if I do need this, I suppose the regex matching of this string to extract it for every new instance of a *Ang would be very inefficient?! So only part solution...

Comment: Even in bash you don't have the string behind `*`, and you said you are switching from bash... I don't think I've ever encountered a use case for getting the string behind the shell's glob pattern (as opposed to the string behind regex)